# vim - delete all lines starting with datetime that dont contain a classname

Tags: vim, sed

I am wondering how to delete all lines that start with some string `12/25/2015` unless they contain a string 'ApplicationMaster'.  I want lines that don't start with `12/25/2015` to not be deleted.

In sed I can do this `cat file.txt | sed '/^12\/25\/2015/ { /ApplicationMaster/!d }` but in vim I can't figure out a general way of saying "For all rows that match a given regex, apply this sub/delete pattern on it".

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it with Vim:

```
:v /ApplicationMaster/ s!\m^12/25/2015.*\n!!
```

Another way, with negative lookahead:

```
:g -\m^12/25/2015\(.*\<ApplicationMaster\>\)\@!- d
```

Comment: what is the `\m` for?

Comment: @anthonybell It makes the regexp independent of the `magic` option.  See `:h /\m` and `:h /magic` for details.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply run your buffer through a slightly altered version of your `sed` command:

```
:%!sed '/^12\/25\/2015/ { /ApplicationMaster/\!d }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim ships with `:LogiPat` which will allow boolean logic with patterns. Using `:LogiPat` will set the search register, `@/`. Once the search pattern is set you can easily use `:g` and `:d` to remove the offending lines.

```
:LogiPat "^12/12/2015"&!"ApplicationMaster"
:g//d
```

Note: `:LogiPat`'s regex for this pattern ends up being: `\%(.*^12/12/2015.*\&^\%(\%(ApplicationMaster\)\@!.\)*$\)`

For more help see:

```
:h logipat-man
:h :g
:h :d
:h "/
```